# linearity of deep learning model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

So today I was watching a lecture that is taught by Ian Goodfellow about the adversarial attacks of the deep network. He made an interesting point I don't really understand. He said that for a deep neural network, since the activation function we mostly used is Relu, so the model becomes mostly linear. But the parameter of the network is not linear since the weight we multiply is nonlinear. I don't understand why he said that since when forward propagation we are going through those nonlinear calculations as well. so although the activation function is linear, when we used it to do the task, the model will be nonlinear as well?
The lecture link is right here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIfsB_EYsVI&list=PL3FW7Lu3i5JvHM8ljYj-zLfQRF3EO8sYv&index=16

Anyone understand this and can clarify this for me? Thanks

Comment: Here's the specific moment in the video where Goodfellow says this: https://youtu.be/CIfsB_EYsVI?list=PL3FW7Lu3i5JvHM8ljYj-zLfQRF3EO8sYv&t=1089

Answer (score 1):

For most of the actual activation values at neurons, the neuron is operating in its linear range.

That's all it means.

Comment: It's worth looking at the specific statement from Goodfellow; here's the moment in the video. https://youtu.be/CIfsB_EYsVI?list=PL3FW7Lu3i5JvHM8ljYj-zLfQRF3EO8sYv&t=1089 I think he was making a different point that the function that takes the neural network parameters as input (with a given feature vector held fixed) and returns the network logit values as output is a highly nonlinear function, whereas the function that takes a feature vector as input (with neural network parameters held fixed) and returns the neural network logit values as output is a piecerwise linear function.

Comment: @littleO ok. If I understand you correctly does that mean for example given a CNN, the first case where it's nonlinear is when we pass an image into the model and give an output? Since the image is fixed. And for the second case where it's linear is where we want to do adversial attack where we run gradient ascent on the image while the network parameter itself is fixed?

Comment: If $w$ is a vector containing all the parameters of the neural network, and $x$ is an example to be classified by the neural network, then the logit values that are output by the neural network are a function of both $x$ and $w$. So we could write: $\text{logit values} = f(x,w)$. What Goodfellow is saying is that for a fixed value of $w$, the function $x \mapsto f(x,w)$ is piecewise linear. However, for a fixed value of $x$, the function $w \mapsto f(x,w)$ is highly nonlinear.